# Class library dll dependancy on compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have created class library dll that will be used in application compiled on different PC. Dll is created using Visual Studio 2010 C++. I suppose that application that will be using dll should also be compiled with VS 2010 C++ and not for example VS2012 C++. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

What will happens if executable and DLL PC will have different version of Visual Studio 2010 - for example Professional/Ultimate?

What will happens if these Visual Studio will have different update packages installed?

Comment: It is a very easy way to avoid a lot of trouble.  Designing a DLL so the implementation details don't break the client code is not that easy, you have to give up on a lot of the C++ goodies.  You can't do obvious stuff like returning an std::string or throwing an exception.  The kind of guarantees you need to make memory management and object layout compatible are only provided by a VM runtime.  Not by C++, especially C++11 upset the apple cart.  The VS edition doesn't matter, just the version number.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 allows you to specify a different "Platform Toolset" in the properties page for a project.  So, you can use 2012 to create an application that targets a 2010 Dll.  the application should target the same toolset as the Dll.  The different versions (eg. Professional/Ultimate) should not be a factor because it is the redistributable files (dlls) that matter.